# Проверить столбец DataFrame на равенство нескольким значениям

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Я хочу выделить строки DataFrame, для которых столбец `foo` равен одному из значений:

```
df[(df['foo'] == 'val_1') or (df['foo'] == 'val_2') or (df['foo'] == 'val_3') ... ]
```

Можно ли сделать это как-нибудь более компактно встроенными функциями (что-нибудь по типу isinstance, которому можно передать список из types и проверить, является принадлежит ли объект одному из перечисленных классов)?

Answer (score 4):

Я бы использовал [DataFrame.query(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
values = ['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3']
df.query("foo in @values")
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться isin()

```
df[df['foo'].isin(['val_1', 'val_2'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Или `df[df['foo'].str.contains(['val_1', 'val_2'])]`

Comment: Это совсем не одно и то же

Comment: Ты прав, я задачу неверно себе истолковал.